# Apache Jena Textsearch over multiple fields very slow

Tags: lucene, sparql, jena, fuseki

I'm trying to query a local Apache Jena person database (running on Apache Jena Fuseki 3.17.0) with this SPARQL expression.

```
PREFIX gndo: <https://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#>
PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?y text:query (gndo:surname "Einstein") .
    ?y text:query (gndo:forename "Albert") .
}
```

And it is very, very slow (> 10s), although both fields are indexed:

```
[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
   fuseki:services (
        :myservice
           ) .

:myservice rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    fuseki:name "persondata" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery "query" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpdate "update" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpload "upload" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;
    fuseki:dataset :text_dataset ;
.

text:TextDataset rdfs:subClassOf ja:RDFDataset .

:text_dataset rdf:type text:TextDataset ;
    text:dataset :geodata ;
    text:index <#indexLucene>;
.

:geodata rdf:type tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "data/dataforTDB" ;
.

<#indexLucene> a text:TextIndexLucene ;
    text:directory <file:data/lucenePersonIndex> ;
    text:entityMap <#entMap> ;
    text:analyzer [ a text:StandardAnalyzer ] ;
.

<#entMap> a text:EntityMap ;
    text:defaultField "forename" ;
    text:langField "lang" ;
    text:entityField "uri" ;
    text:map (
        [ text:field "forename" ;
          text:predicate gndo:forename ]
        [ text:field "surname" ;
          text:predicate gndo:surname ]
    ) .
```

If I query only over one of the two fields like this

```
PREFIX gndo: <https://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#>
PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?y text:query (gndo:surname "Einstein") .
}
```

The search is very quick, as expected (< 5ms).
What am I doing wrong? This is how it's described here:
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html

So is it just this slow when done like that? It seems illogical as an AND query should be quicker than OR (I'm using a two text queries with a UNION in another query and it's still very quick).

If it's in any way relevant, I'm sending the query over python3 by using the SPARQLWrapper package.

Any help is much appreciated, I'm very new to working with Lucene, Apache Jena and Fuseki, thanks in advance!

For full information, here is also how the fields are organized in the rdf-database:

```
<https://d-nb.info/gnd/100000096> gndo:variantNameForThePerson "La Peirie, Ambro
ise";
  gndo:variantNameEntityForThePerson _:node1einj54cqx16589985 .

_:node1einj54cqx16589985 gndo:forename "Ambroise";
  gndo:surname "La Peirie" .
```

I found this piece of information in the Apache Jena documentation now:

> In principle it should be possible to extend Jena to allow for
> creating documents with multiple searchable fields by extending
> org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetChangesBatched such as with
> org.apache.jena.query.text.TextDocProducerEntities; however, this form
> of extension is not currently (Jena 3.13.1) functional.

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, is this referring to my problem? So it's just not possible to run an AND-query over two indexed fields at the moment?

Comment: which version do you use? What is the Fuseki setup? Did you try it without SPARQL wrapper e.g. via curl or tdbquery? How large is the result per? And the result per triple pattern?

Comment: @UninformedUser I added more info to the OP concerning version number. I tried now using curl and I still get the same performance. Not sure what you mean by the last two questions exactly, but I get 12 results from the request using two fields, taking 13s to respond and I get 315 results from the request using only one field, taking 24ms to respond. Thanks for looking into my question!

Comment: It will be faster to combine the text;query into one Lucene query.  "forename:Albert AND surname:Einstein" Jena does not use the SPARQL structure to rewrite the Lucene query strings.

Comment: @AndyS this is not possible with the "default integration model" as each field aka each triple will be one document, see https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html#queries-across-multiple-fields - there is another section which mentions a possible extended model, but the documentation is just a sketch there: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html#multiple-fields-per-document